# Why Django Swagger is not showing docs for urls that has permissions IsAuthenticated?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-swagger

In my api default permmision class is 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated' and django swagger is not showing docs for any url.

My REST_FRAMEWORK settings is:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

And my swagger_settings is :

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'USE_SESSION_AUTH': False,
    'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'api_key': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'in': 'header',
            'name': 'Authorization'
        }
    },
```

So how can I show authenticated endpoints in django swagger.

Comment: did you get it working? facing same issue

Answer (score 3):

This topic actually established a great discussion [in GitHub](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/58). It seems like you are trying to access views that have `IsAuthenticated` as permission classes and likely they're forbidden if you're not authenticated yet.

You can just add `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` in your DRF settings, in order to make those endpoints accessible via Swagger:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
         'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
         'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication
    )
}
```